# CMAKE libintl-8.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks

I've been looking for solutions, and honestly I'm stuck.

[image: Screenshot]

I'm trying to install Box2D, as you can see by the file paths.

Anyway, this prompt appears several times before the following:

[image: Screenshot]

```
The CXX compiler identification is unknown
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:54 (message):
  The C++ compiler "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe" is not able to compile a simple
  test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: C:/Users/alexm/Documents/Box2D/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_31089/fast"

  C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_31089.dir\build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_31089.dir/build


  mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory
  'C:/Users/alexm/Documents/Box2D/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


  Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_31089.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj


  C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_31089.dir\testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj
  -c
  C:\Users\alexm\Documents\Box2D\Build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCXXCompiler.cxx



  CMakeFiles\cmTC_31089.dir\build.make:64: recipe for target
  'CMakeFiles/cmTC_31089.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj' failed


  mingw32-make.exe[1]: ***
  [CMakeFiles/cmTC_31089.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj] Error 1


  mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory
  'C:/Users/alexm/Documents/Box2D/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


  Makefile:125: recipe for target 'cmTC_31089/fast' failed


  mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTC_31089/fast] Error 2






  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/alexm/Documents/Box2D/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/alexm/Documents/Box2D/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

So, there's the error. I'm trying to install it on code::blocks with MinGW, I've currently got 2 copies of MinGW installed, one that's located in the code::blocks folder and the other is in my root drive, I installed MinGW seperately to fix this problem.

This is my first time using CMake, I'm trying to get it to work with my sfml project on code::blocks in C++.

Apologies if I missed anything, if you spot any information you'd need don't hesitate to comment!

Comment: I would start investigating the first error. I mean is `libintl-8.dll` is missing from your computer?? Look at the path for `C:/MinGW/bin`

Comment: You're stuck?  You didn't put libintl into google and pick any of the hundreds of hits?

Comment: It is in both MinGW directories (The one in code::blocks installation folder and the one in the MinGW root folder)

Comment: Then is C:\MinGW\bin part of your windows PATH environment variable?

Comment: Apologies about the late reply, this was in fact one of the issues. My PATH had the directory C:\MinGW\ for some reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to system variables and add

> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin

to your path

Answer (score 2):

You download `libintl-8.dll` and copy to `C:\MinGW\bin`:

https://www.dll-files.com/libintl-8.dll.html

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should run Cmake as admin. I had the same problem, worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried every solution proposed below and did not work for me then I realized that CMake uses **C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\mingw32\bin** instead of **C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin** so I copied the "dll" files to that folder. If that does not work for you try adding **C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\mingw32\bin** to your path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I was runing cmake with compability to win 7,
when I untick it, it started work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).