# cudart64_80.dll is missing

Tags: c++, cuda, cmake

I use `CMake-gui 3.8` for making project `gadgetron` (https://github.com/gadgetron/gadgetron). The code generator is "Eclipse CDT4-MinGW Makefiles". The `Configure` button click generates error as

```
The program can't start because cudart64_80.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

The file `cudart64_80.dll` is at location C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin and this path is included in system variable `Path`.

Followed the links:
[libgmp-10.dll is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951938/libgmp-10-dll-is-missing) and 
[CMAKE libintl-8.dll is missing from your computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834729/cmake-libintl-8-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer)

I am also mentioning the `cuda` related Confiugre output log below:

```
Found CUDA: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v8.0 (found suitable version "8.0", minimum required is "5.5") 
CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE = C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v8.0/include
CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY = C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v8.0/lib/x64/cudart.lib
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try copying `cudart64_80` to the location of the executable you are trying to run.

Comment: My understanding is that the statement `find_package(CUDA_advanced)` will locate `FindCUDA_advanced.cmake`.
In `FindCUDA_advanced.cmake`,
the code
`cuda_find_helper_file(cuda_compute_capability c)
try_run(....`
tries to execute `cuda_compute_capability.c`. 
After this, 
`COMPILE_RESULT_VAR` is set to `TRUE` and `RUN_RESULT_VAR` is set as `FALIED_TO_RUN`. I copied `cudart64_80.dll` parallel to `cuda_compute_capability.c` file. But the error `cudart64_80.dll is missing from your computer` still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve the problem by creating a batch file for executing cmake-gui.exe with path set to location of folder containing cudart64_80.dll. Thanks to the comments.

```
@echo off
set path=C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-6.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1\mingw64\bin;E:\IMRI\Software\doxygen-1.8.12.windows.x64.bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin;
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake-gui.exe"
```